# Are there any healing or medicinal meditation in Hinduism?

Tags: yoga, tantra, ayurveda

In the realm of spiritual practices, various traditions incorporate healing techniques, such as *Reiki* in Buddhism and the *Siddha* form of treatment in southern India. However, despite the extensive development of Tantra and Yoga in Hinduism, there is a curiosity about whether there are general meditations for healing or self-healing mentioned in Indian texts, particularly Upanishads. *This inquiry is not aimed at clinical data or medical advice but seeks insights into ancient meditation and yoga techniques for promoting well-being.*

Buddhism features practices akin to Reiki, and the Medicine Buddha is revered for healing through the manipulation of energy and herbs. Similarly, practices involving the opening of chakras for treating ailments are present. **In the context of Hinduism, Tantra and Yoga have undergone significant development, yet there's a quest to uncover meditation techniques specifically for healing purposes without reliance on external elements like herbs.**

While there is awareness of Siddha treatments in southern India, information on healing meditations in Hinduism, **especially from classic shrutis/smritis, remains less prevalent. The question delves into whether ancient texts prescribe meditation or yoga techniques for self-healing and disease prevention**, with a preference for methods rooted in Raja Yoga.

**What I Need:**

1. Insights into general meditation practices for healing in Indian spiritual traditions, especially Upanishads or references to such practices.
2. Information on any syllables or mantras from Upanishads associated with promoting a long and healthy life.
3. Knowledge about any healing concepts in Ayurvedic texts that involve meditation or self-healing techniques.

**What I Don't Need:**

1. **Clinical data or medical advice** – the focus is on traditional
   meditation and yoga practices.
2. **General information about Buddhism or Siddha treatments** – the
   emphasis is on Hindu practices, particularly those mentioned in
   Upanishads or related texts.

Answer (score 1):

From my knowledge, "ART-OF-VASHEEYA" is part of Meditation on God with "Om Chants" with body not taking food for atleast a day. This is called Healing meditation.
"Foods we eat make us forget meditation and since we forget to meditate we loose our body medications(hormones & T cells) naturally produced inside".

```
              HEALER
```

Though one cannot equate meditation gorectly to a doctor who measures many parameters of human body, meditation is still useful in reducing all parameters thus healing body out of nervous illnesss.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).